# Intellij IDEA debug Maven-GWT project with specific PROFILE

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, gwt, profile

I have maven gwt project with many profiles which i use for replacement some params in .properties files. Can i start debugging gwt application in Intellij Idea with specific maven profile?

Answer (score 2):

You can choose the active maven profiles in the "Maven project" side panel and also in the maven run/debug configuration using the "Profiles" configuration parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven side panel can be opened with "View > Tool windows > Maven". Note that the "Profiles" section will be at the top of the list of Maven projects and it will only appear if at least one Maven project/module has at least two Profiles.

For more details, see here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-profiles.html#activate_maven_profiles